# Terraform issue generating random password in for each

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to generate a password when creating users in azuread, I have a sample code below. I get the following error: `password` is required when creating a new user. Any help is highly appreciated. Don't worry about the vars.tf, I have a variable users and a json file with user information which is used in the for_each loop.

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azuread = {
            source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
            version = "~> 2.0.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "azuread" {}

resource "random_password" "example" {
    length  = 16
    special = true
    lower   = true
    upper   = true
    numeric = true
}

resource "azuread_user" "users" {
    for_each              = var.users
    
    user_principal_name   = each.value.user_principal_name
    display_name          = each.value.display_name
    given_name            = each.value.given_name
    surname               = each.value.surname
    job_title             = each.value.job_title
    mail_nickname         = each.value.mail_nickname
    company_name          = each.value.company_name
    password              = random_password.example.result

    force_password_change = true
}
```

I also want to generate a unique password for each user creation, but not sure if this mechanism is catched in the for_each. The code do work if I type the string manually, e.g. password = "123".

Comment: Not sure if that can be done, but you might have to apply the same `for_each` logic in the random resource so you can have a different password per user.

Comment: Thanks, will attempt. Used this as a resource btw: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/password

Comment: Yeah, I know, based on the code from your question, so that's good. :)

Comment: I don't see how that error could be coming from that code. As mentioned above, you are setting the same password on every user (which is bad) but it shouldn't be giving you that error message, since it's a non-null password value.

Comment: If there's any alternative solution, please let me know :-) I dont want to push e.g. "SecretP@sswd99!" to GitHub as they use in this example https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/user.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at the latest version of the `azuread` provider but it says the `password` argument is optional: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/user#password.

Comment: Seems like its not up to date, I recieve Error: `password` is required when creating a new user.. :/

Comment: Ah, ok try this `version = "~> 2.0"` and run `terraform init` again.

Comment: Seems to work without password after changing version.. might be better, they will get link anyway through email which I assume I take advantage of email auth rather than my own. Thank you both for assistance :-)

Comment: Hi @emilk if you solved your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users was created without password.

Passwords was required for the azuread version used.

Bumped the version to avoid this.